# Selenium C# - Check if a value is not on a table

Tags: c#, selenium

At one of my test cases, if based on some configurations, determined values on a table should not be displayed.

I've made a code to show up a message if a **predicted** value not appears, as following:

```
public void AssertRecord(string recordExpected)
{
    try
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(recordExpected, RecordGridCell.GetGridCellAtPosition1BasedOnAnyValue(recordExpected));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(recordExpected + " not found.");
    }
}
```

By the way, the function above **GetGridCellAtPosition1BasedOnAnyValue** is here:

```
public static string GetGridCellAtPosition1BasedOnAnyValue(this IWebElement table, string value)
{
    UtilFunctions.WaitForLoadingBar();
    IList<IWebElement> tableRow = table.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tr//td[text()='" + value + "']//ancestor::tr//td[1]"));
    return tableRow.First().GetAttribute("innerHTML");
}
```

So, with the code I got today, I get an **output** saying, for example, "Chocolate Bar not found.". If the value exists, it throws nothing.

My **problem** is: if is there any value on the table that shouldn't be there and that can't be predicted, it will not be reported.

I need help to find a way to be reported if there's **any** value on the table that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Do you have a pre-defined list of what records are expected in the table?

Comment: @Bᴜᴅɪ Yep, It's defined by the test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a pre-defined list of what records are expected in the table, I would use that list and check it against the actual list of records in the table via [`Enumerable.Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here's some code to give you an idea:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

var expectedRecords = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var actualRecords   = new List<string> { "A", "C", "E" };

//var actualRecords = table.FindElements(".//tr//td[1]")
//                         .Select(e => e.GetAttribute("innerHTML"))
//                         .ToList();

var notFoundRecords = expectedRecords.Except(actualRecords); // [ "B", "D" ]
var invalidRecords  = actualRecords.Except(expectedRecords); // [ "E" ]
```

This will give you lists of both what's not in the actual list but should be (`notFoundRecords`), and what's in the actual list but should not be (`invalidRecords`).